# powershell - inserting 7-zip parameters as variables

Tags: powershell, scripting, 7zip

I am trying to run a script which archive specific directory and exclude some type of files. Problem is that if i try to insert some of parameters to main 7z command - those parameters doesn't work here is my code:

```
$source = "c:\source"
$destination = "d:\dest"
$date = get-date -UFormat "%d-%m-%Y"
$name = "D-"+$date+".zip"
$ExcludeFileTypes= "-x!'*.css' -x!'*.exe' -x!'*.dll' -x!'*.iso' -x!'*.ace' -x!'*.arj' -x!'*.jar' -x!'*.bz2' -x!'*.lha' -x!'*.lzh' -x!'*.rar' -x!'*.zip' -x!'*.tar' -x!'*.tgz'"
7z a "$destination$name" "$source" -r $ExcludeFileTypes -mx=9
```

If i replace `$ExcludeFileTypes` with its value - 7z command works. I have no idea where could be a problem.
I guess that I can't work with variables like that.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue while ago trying to execute msi installers from command line. Try executing it like this:

```
$cmdargs = "a $destination$name $source -r $ExcludeFileTypes -mx=9"
Start-Process -FilePath c:\tools\7z.exe -ArgumentList $cmdargs
```

Comment: unfortunately it did not work. Anyway thanks for tip.

Comment: really? what error did you get? On your snippet the $ExcludeFileTypes is missing a closing double quotes at the end. Maybe that's the reason.

Comment: And i'm sorry for those double quotes at the end of iniciallization of $ExcludeFileTypes variable. I had them in script and somehow didn't type them in here.

Comment: That's odd I've actually tested the script and it worked out ok for me. I'll post my example in a gist so you can see if you have something missing:
https://gist.github.com/perezgb/e05b341655e7eca2065a